# Approximation of integration

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, approximate-integration

I want to estimate the integral $\int_0^{1/2}\ln(1+ \frac{x^2}{4})$
with error at most $10^{-4}$.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

I have calculated the power series of $\ln(1+ \frac{x^2}{4})$ which is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{n= \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+2)\cdot 2^{2n+1}}x^{2n+2},$$

and radius of convergence $= 1/2$. Now calculate

$$\int_0^{1/2}\sum_{n=0}^{n= \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)\cdot 2^{2n+1}}x^{2n+1}\,dx =  \sum_{n=0}^{n= \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+3)(2n+2)\cdot 2^{2n+1}}(\frac{1}{2})^{2n+3}.$$

Comment: The start is strong, but I still think your initial Taylor series is off (like I said, inserting $\frac{x^2}{4}$ into the Taylor expansion of Ln(1+z) should give you only even powers of x.  Once that is sorted out, you will have an alternating series.  What's the error if you cut if off at some point?

Comment: Better! And if you cut an alternating series, the error is no worse than the first omitted term.  The terms of your series go to 0 very fast indeed so you don't need many terms at all.

Answer (score 5):

The taylor series you put in the comment is wrong. You should get 
$$
\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)= \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^4}{32}+\frac{x^6}{192}-\frac{x^8}{1024}+O(x^{10})
$$

Integrating up to the 2nd power you get 
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \frac{x^2}{4}dx = \frac{1}{96} \simeq 0.010417
$$

Integrating up to the 4th power you get 
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^4}{32} dx = \frac{ 157}{15360 } =0.01022135416
$$

Meanwhile the real result is 
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{4}\right) dx = \frac12 \left(-2+\ln(17/16)+8 \tan^{-1}(1/4)\right) \simeq 0.010227
$$
Since when we integrate up to the 4rth power we left out the terms with order $O(x^{2n})$ for $n> 2$, we get a result with error of order less than $10^{-4}$, indeed
$$
0.010227-0.01022135416=  0.00000564584< 0.0001= 10^{-4}
$$

Comment: How do you show that the order of error is atmost $10^{-4}$?

Comment: @biswa I have made an edit clarifying this. Do you see it now ?

Comment: Yup!! Thank you very much for your rigorous answer

Comment: Glad I could help you @biswa

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín You need one more term to reduce the error to less than $10^{-4}$.

Comment: @Dr.MV You are right. I interpreted as error of almost $10^{-4}$ and not at most at most $10^{-4}$, disadvantages of being non native speaker. I will make an edit later, thanks a lot !!

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín No worry.  ;-)) +1 in advance for the edited solution!

Comment: Done @Dr.MV thanks again !!

Answer (score 2):

The integral can be computed analytically:

$x \ln \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(x^2+4\right)\right)-2 x+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$

and with the limits becomes

$\frac{1}{2} \left(-2+\ln \left(\frac{17}{16}\right)+8 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)$

or

$0.010227$.